# iOS AppDelegate.m: Handling openUrl RCTLinkingManager and Twitter - Duplicate declaration of method 'application:openURL:options:'

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I need to add `DeepLinking` to my `React Native` app, and as mentioned in docs I need to add the method above `@and`.

```
// Add this above `@end`:
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
   openURL:(NSURL *)url
   options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
}
```

I've added this method, but I also have similar one for Twitter login. Here's my `AppDelegate.m`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options {
  return [[Twitter sharedInstance] application:app openURL:url options:options];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
   openURL:(NSURL *)url
   options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
}


@end
```

I get an error:
`Duplicate declaration of method 'application:openURL:options:'`

How can it be solved? I'm not an iOS developer, so it's hard to figure out, but I think both two methods should be somehow combined.

Answer (score 2):

As the error suggests, you can not have multiple functions with the same signature.
A simple solution here is merging your implementation into one, like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options {
  return ([[Twitter sharedInstance] application:app openURL:url options:options] || [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options]);
}
```

Comment: I have conflicts between these methods. Twitter sharedInstance is invoked on every RCTLinkingManager invoke. Is it possible to separate them using if?

Comment: It depends on your need. You can filter by the URL and invoke Twitter only for a specific URL format, otherwise, call your own handler. Basically, you have the URL there so you can control which should be called.

Comment: How can this be done? I need Twitter to be called only when I use Twitter auth, and RCTLinking when I use deeplinks. Currently, on every deeplink Twitter is invoked

Comment: The easiest way is deciding which handler should be called based on the host of the opened URL.